# What are this sensor especially those at tips?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airplane, sensors

This is an image of an RQ-7 B UAV what are those sensors marked in red circles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tall bump at the front is "tactical common data link" ([from this video](https://youtu.be/NXg_Yfj9xKw?t=84))

The wingtip antenna is a com relay antennae [based on this article](https://defense-update.com/20120504_australian_shadow_operational.html)